# Token request sends a redirect instead of token or error

Tags: salesforce1-app, curl, accesstoken

I have trial Enterprise account and I can successfully obtain a token with the below curl.

```
curl -v https://eu31.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -d "client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -d "username=nipun@force.com" -d "password=xxxxxxxxx" -k
```

Since I can't use SCIM APIs with an Enterprise trial, created another developer trial account and configured the exact same as previous. But now, the **exact same** request template doesn't return an error nor a token. Instead, it sends a redirect as below.

```
curl -v https://ap17.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -d "client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -d "username=nipundev@abc.com" -d "password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -k
```

Response (No response payload. Just a redirect.)

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: https://ap17.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

Between the two requests, only the host name(copied from the browser URL) and the credentials are different.And they are correct.

Can anyone think of a reason for this?

Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.

For some reason, SF developer accounts can't use the browser URL hostname for token call. You have to change the hostname as below.

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

Hope this will help someone.

Cheers.